# Fresh install of Liquibase 3.10 is failing

Tags: oracle, windows-10, liquibase

I have just installed Liquibase 3.10 using the Windows installer on Win10 64-bit. When I run the command "liquibase --help" from the command line, the liquibase.bat file fails with the following error;

="=="" ( was unexpected at this time.

I can see by looking at the batch file the error occurs in the section where it is manipulating the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

On my system, there is no JAVA_HOME environment variable.

I'm not an expert Windows batch file programmer, so I need help with this!

PS. Liquibase is installed in the following path: C:\Program Files\liquibase

Comment: Hi, do you have Java installed?  If so where?  You may just be able to create a JAVA_HOME variable.  To discuss with the Liquibase team, you can chat us: https://discord.gg/9yBwMtj

Comment: Yes, that worked for me.I set JAVA_HOME to "C:\Program Files\liquibase\jre", and the "liquibase --help" command is now working.

Comment: Glad that worked!  We are working to fix the installer issue so that you don't have to do this work around.